# jQuery/CSS: Full-sized image and centered

Tags: jquery, css

Basically, I want to put in the center of the website/screen an image of a magazine.

This image should, however, fit all in the screen.

I've tried something like:

```
.magazine{
    background: url(../img/magazine.jpg) top center no-repeat;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The image gets on center for sure... but it get's way big and all cut off.

How can I get it on center but with the size of the screen?

Thought about getting the window size with jQuery and apply to it... but I am not quite sure that would work and would be on center.

Answer (score 0):

You can give it a `background-size: cover;` and it will be as tall as the container if it is taller than wider or as wide as the container if it is wider than taller.
Or you can set it as `background-size: 100% 100%;` to stretch it, but it might not respect the image's proportions.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you where you need to go.  The filters will assist in IE compatibility.

```
.magazine {
    background-image: url(../img/magazine.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="../img/magazine.jpg", sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="../img/magazine.jpg", sizingMethod='scale')";

}
```